# android notification show not only in bar

Tags: android, notifications

I am working with android and notifications. Everything is ok and the notification icon shows up in the notification bar.

But I wanted the notification to appear sliding down the top of the device (just as in whatsapp notifications we receive)...

Are those the same notifications? How to accomplish?

Thanks